# Looking for a book about people who could shape shift into dragons

Tags: story-identification, books, dragons

The cover was white and had a red swirly mask on it. I think the first book started with her flying. There were hunters and the main character got captured and they did experiments and locked them in cells and stuff.

I'm pretty sure that, before all that, they lived in this village thing hidden by people with magic or fog.

Comment: Maybe this will help finding it: https://www.goodreads.com/list/show/13569.Best_Dragon_Shapeshifter_Romance_Novels

Answer (score 2):

Could this possibly be the [***Firelight***](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6448470-firelight) series by Sophie Jordan?

> Marked as special at an early age, Jacinda knows her every move is watched. But she longs for freedom to make her own choices. When she breaks the most sacred tenet among her kind, she nearly pays with her life. Until a beautiful stranger saves her. A stranger who was sent to hunt those like her. For Jacinda is a draki, a descendant of dragons whose greatest defense is her secret ability to shift into human form.
>
> Forced to flee into the mortal world with her family, Jacinda struggles to adapt to her new surroundings. The only bright light is Will. Gorgeous, elusive Will who stirs her inner draki to life. Although she is irresistibly drawn to him, Jacinda knows Will's dark secret: He and his family are hunters. She should avoid him at all costs. But her inner draki is slowly slipping away;if it dies she will be left as a human forever. She'll do anything to prevent that. Even if it means getting closer to her most dangerous enemy.
>
> Mythical powers and breathtaking romance ignite in this story of a girl who defies all expectations and whose love crosses an ancient divide.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility: The [***Talon***](https://www.goodreads.com/series/96817-talon) series by Julie Kagawa.

> The series revolves around dragons with the ability to disguise themselves as humans and an order of warriors sworn to eradicate them. The dragons of TALON and the Order of St. George have been at war with each other for centuries. The fabled creatures, whose existence is unknown by the general public, are determined to rule the world. Their foes, a legendary society of dragon slayers, are equally bent on driving the fabled beasts into extinction. However, when a young dragon and a hardened slayer unknowingly befriend each other, it has severe repercussions for both organizations.

Currently the titles in this series are: Talon, Rogue, Soldier, Legion, Inferno.